# ADD Column - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Como eu posso adicionar uma coluna à uma tabela no banco de dados utilizando django?
Tentei a seguinte migração e não atualizou minha tabela:

from django.db import models, migrations

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('api', '0001_initial')
    ]
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='item',
        name='name',
        field=models.CharField(max_length=45)
    )
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A não ser que vc não esteja utilizando o ORM do django, essa operação é feita automaticamente pelo framework. Siga os passos abaixo:

Vá no arquivo models.py da sua app, na definição do model (classe) e simplesmente adicione a coluna, por exemplo, digamos que a definição original seja:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

E vc deseja adicionar a coluna `age`, altere a classe Person para:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

Então na raiz do seu projeto, utilizando o script manage.py, crie a migration com o comando:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

Finalmente atualize o banco de dados com o comando:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```